# Fill treeview from custom array of objects. Recursion call

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, recursion, treeview

I'm using [treeview](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-tree-view/) to display my hierarchical data.

I have following array of objects:

```
const data = [
      { id: 1, hierarchyid: "/", level: 0, name: "Mhz" },
      { id: 2, hierarchyid: "/2/", level: 1, name: "SMT" },
      { id: 3, hierarchyid: "/3/", level: 1, name: "QC" },
      { id: 4, hierarchyid: "/3/4/", level: 2, name: "Tester" },
      { id: 5, hierarchyid: "/3/5/", level: 2, name: "Operator" },
    ];
```

I need to fill my treeview with this data.
What I did so far:

```
getTreeItems(node, nodes) {
    const filtered = nodes.filter(
      (n) => n.hierarchyid.includes(node.hierarchyid) && n.level != node.level
    );

    return (
      <TreeItem
        key={node.id}
        nodeId={node.hierarchyid}
        label={node.name}
        onClick={() => onClicked(node)}
      >
        {filtered.length > 0
          ? filtered.map((node) => this.getTreeItems(node, filtered))
          : null}
      </TreeItem>
    );
  }
```

And rendering:

```
render() {
    // The data comes from Server
    const data = [
      { id: 1, hierarchyid: "/", level: 0, name: "Mhz" },
      { id: 2, hierarchyid: "/2/", level: 1, name: "SMT" },
      { id: 3, hierarchyid: "/3/", level: 1, name: "QC" },
      { id: 4, hierarchyid: "/3/4/", level: 2, name: "Tester" },
      { id: 5, hierarchyid: "/3/5/", level: 2, name: "Operator" },
    ];
    return (
      <TreeView
        aria-label="file system navigator"
        defaultCollapseIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
        defaultExpandIcon={<ChevronRightIcon />}
        sx={{ height: "auto", flexGrow: 1, width: "auto", overflowY: "auto" }}
      >
        {this.getTreeItems(
          { id: 1, hierarchyid: "/", level: 0, name: "Mhz" },
          data
        )}
      </TreeView>
    );
  }
}
```

This giving me view like:

```
+Mhz
 +SMT
 +QC
  +Tester
  +Operator
 +Tester    // they shouldn't be displayed
 +Operator // they have already rendered as child under QC
```

My problem is can not exclude already rendered nodes.

**Update**

MUI TreeView supports special `JSON` data for its nodes. So converting `array` to `JSON` also solves the problem. Something like that:

```
const data = {
      id: 1,
      hierarchyid: "/",
      level: 0,
      name: "Mhz",
      children: [
        {
          id: 2,
          hierarchyid: "/2/",
          level: 1,
          name: "SMT"
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          hierarchyid: "/3/",
          level: 1,
          name: "QC",
          children: [
            {
              id: 4,
              hierarchyid: "/3/4/",
              level: 2,
              name: "Tester"
            },
            {
              id: 5,
              hierarchyid: "/3/5/",
              level: 2,
              name: "Operator"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    };
```

the array of objects came from Server, so how can I make this Json from array data?

Comment: Have you tried mapping only the items from the object that you want? i.e. doing something like this in your render function. 
```data.map((element) => {
   if(element.id in listOfItemsRequired){
        return element;
   }
})```

Comment: @SampurnG all items are required. Item will be unnecessary when it rendered already.

Comment: So you don't want to display the items which are at level 2 right?

Comment: I want to display all items, but once. Example: `SMT` and `QC` are level=1. And `Tester` and `Operator`  are level=2, child of level=1 `QC`. And they already rendered under `QC`. What I want, they should not be rendered again under `Mhz`, level=0

Comment: Okay got it, wait I'll post a code sandbox which will be similar to the given documentation. As per my understanding, the data object that you've created, needs to be modified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we write a quick function to test whether one hierarchy id is the direct descendant of another, then we can use it to write a simple recursive version:

```js
const isChild = (prefix) => ({hierarchyid}) =>
  hierarchyid .startsWith (prefix) 
  && /^[^\/]*\/$/ .test (hierarchyid .slice (prefix .length))

const nest = (xs, prefix = '') => 
  xs .filter (isChild (prefix)) .map ((x, _, __, children = nest (xs, x .hierarchyid)) => ({
    ...x, 
    ... (children .length ? {children} : {})
  }))

const data = [{id: 1, hierarchyid: "/", level: 0, name: "Mhz"}, {id: 2, hierarchyid: "/2/", level: 1, name: "SMT"}, {id: 3, hierarchyid: "/3/", level: 1, name: "QC"}, {id: 4, hierarchyid: "/3/4/", level: 2, name: "Tester"}, {id: 5, hierarchyid: "/3/5/", level: 2, name: "Operator"}]


console .log (nest (data))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

`isChild` checks whether the hierarchy id starts with our prefix and if the remainder has only one `'/'`, at the very end.

`nest` is not as efficient as it might be, as it scans the whole array for each node.  But I wouldn't worry about it until I had tens of thousands of entries.

If you don't mind having some empty `children` arrays on your leaves, it's simpler still:

```js
const nest = (xs, prefix = '') => 
  xs .filter (isChild (prefix)) .map ((x) => ({
    ...x,
    children: nest (xs, x .hierarchyid)
  }))
```

Answer (score 1):

SO I've looked at the documentation and they've clearly mentioned a way to design your data object in such a way so that the hierarchy can be shown without multiple nodes repeating.

[Try going through this once](https://codesandbox.io/embed/richobjecttreeview-material-demo-forked-e2uq78?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) and change your render functions according to the documentation, you can probably get your desired result.

```
const data: RenderTree = {
  id: "root",
  name: "Mhz",
  children: [
    {
      id: "1",
      name: "SMT"
    },
    {
      id: "3",
      name: "QZ",
      children: [
        {
          id: "4",
          name: "Tester"
        },
        {
          id: "4",
          name: "Operator"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};
```

Comment: Yes I've already done with that. But I want to fill that with my own array. Anyway, okay, how can I change my array to `desired json` data wich required by `mui treeview`?

Comment: Just check the files in the code sandbox(Demo.tsx), I've edited it, you can try something similar, If this helped you can accept it as an answer and close this thread

Comment: you did not understand the question.

Comment: updated the question, look, can you convert data `array` to desired `JSON`?

Comment: I've added the data json to my answer, I'm sorry but you'll have to be more clear, i cannot understand what you mean. It is already a JSON object, what else should i convert it in?

Comment: data comes from API, as you see it's not in `desired` format as required by `mui tree`. So we have to option, filling the tree with some kind of `logic` or making this `data` to `desired format`

Comment: Oh okay i got it, for that it would be fairly simple, but it will take a little time and it'll be fairly lengthy. I'd recommend you to do this yourself as it is a good exercise to familiarise yourself with array traversals. Also breaking down your hierarchyId into an array would simplify things a lot more. I'll try to post a solution once i get off work.